# python pandas-extracting a portion of a string based on the pattern around it

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a string column that follows a following pattern:

```
yariyada up to a maximum of (number)% yariyada
```

For example, like this.

```
will be granted up to a maximum of 75.5% If less, then nothing
```

I want to create another column that extracts that number that comes between "up to a maximum of" and "%".

So far I'm only able to detect if the string column contains that pattern, using .contains method.

If this is of any elucidation, in Stata (I'm a stata user), I would use regexm to break the string into parts and use regexs to retreive the parts. I'm wondering if Pandas has a similar, or better!, function.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) method *to ind groups in each string using passed regular expression*

```
df['col_name'].str.extract('up to a maximum of (.*)%')
```

Will give you a new column with number extracted

Comment: woah, that was quick and simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

bigtable

color   region  finish
red, yellow AK, NV, CA  a, b,c
red, blue   CA,TX, NV   a,c, p
blue, red   TX,CA, AK   p,a, c
blue, yellow    TX,CA, NV   p, c, a
yellow, red AK,CA,NV    c, b, a
yellow,blue CA,TX, NV   c, a, b

```
    list = list(bigtable)
    for index in range(len(list)):
       bigtable1[list[index]] = bigtable1[list[index]].str.split(',', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sort(x)).str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)
```